# Reordering indexed expressions (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, representation-theory

To me, it appears always as a little 'magic' when people reorder expressions,
indexed by highly complex combinations of permutations and I would like to know in deep and formally what
really is going on.

For example consider the following easy identity:

$
\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}x_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes x_{\sigma(k)}=
\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}x_{\sigma(2)}\otimes x_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes x_{\sigma(k)}
$

where $S_k$ is the set of all permutations of an $k$-element set.
Of course this identity is true, since every possible combination is already
an element of $S_k$, but how can I really proof the previous equation? Obviously expressions like the previous example can be arbitrary complicated and therefore a formal step by step algorithm would be desireable.

Moreover expressions like the previous one often contain signs and gradings and stuff like that. So a formal method is necessary.

My assumptions are the following:

$\bullet $ The permutation group has a representations on some mathematical 
structure.

Can someone explain how we formally correct "reorder" i.e. change the indices of expressions indexed by permutations?

Comment: Any bijection on a finite index set reorders the summands of a finite sum and hence yields the same sum. Do you really need to prove that? Or do you want a proof that we are indeed simply permuting the index set?

Comment: I want to know how this is applied in these expressions. Especially if a lot of signs and gradings ect. are involved. How do you use the proposition "Any bijection on a finite index set reorders the summands of a finite sum and hence yields the same sum" in problems like the previous one? Is it precomposition?